# Why does my radio buttons not send through to my emails

Tags: php, html

I am sending values from a web form to an email but the radio buttons does not send through any values.

This is just some off the code everything else works except for these radio buttons all the other values sends through to the email but not the radio buttons please any one that can help.

HTML

```
<div style="float: left;">
<label for="DDoS" id="lbl" style="padding-right: 30px;">Data Destruction-At your site</label><label class="radio-inline"><input name="DDoS" type="radio" value="Yes" id="DDoS1" />Yes</label> <label class="radio-inline"><input name="DDoS" type="radio" id="DDoS2" value="No" checked="checked"/>No</label> <label for="NoHDD0"># of HDD&#39;s</label> <input class="form-control" name="NoHDD0" placeholder="0" size="10" type="text" /><br />
<br />
<label for="DSoS" id="lbl" style="padding-right: 40px;">Data Sanitation-At your site</label> <label class="radio-inline"><input name="DSoS" type="radio" value="Yes" id="DSoS1"/>Yes</label> <label class="radio-inline"><input name="DSoS" type="radio" id="DSoS2" value="No" checked="checked"/>No</label> <label for="NoHDD1"># of HDD&#39;s</label> <input class="form-control" name="NoHDD1" placeholder="0" size="10" type="text" /><br />
<br />
<label for="DDoOS" id="lbl" style="padding-right: 38px;">Data Destruction-At our site</label> <label class="radio-inline"><input name="DDoOS" type="radio" value="Yes" id="DDoOS1"/>Yes</label> <label class="radio-inline"><input name="DDoOS" type="radio" value="No" id="DDoOS2" checked="checked"/>No</label> <label for="NoHDD2"># of HDD&#39;s</label> <input class="form-control" name="NoHDD2" placeholder="0" size="10" type="text" /><br />
<br />
<label for="DSoOS" id="lbl" style="padding-right: 48px;">Data Sanitation-At our site</label> <label class="radio-inline"><input name="DSoOS" type="radio" value="Yes" id="DSoOS1"/>Yes</label> <label class="radio-inline"><input name="DSoOS" type="radio" id=""DSoS2 value="No" checked="checked"/>No</label> <label for="NoHDD3"># of HDD&#39;s</label> <input class="form-control" name="NoHDD3" placeholder="0" size="10" type="text" /><br />
</div>
```

PHP

```
!isset($_POST['DDoS'] ) ||
!isset($_POST['NoHDD0'] )||
!isset($_POST['DSoS'] ) ||
!isset($_POST['NoHDD1'] ) ||
!isset($_POST['DDoOS'] ) ||
!isset($_POST['NoHDD2'] )||
!isset($_POST['DSoOS'] ) ||
!isset($_POST['NoHDD3'] )||


$DDoS = $_POST['DDoS']; // not required
$NoHDD0 = $_POST['NoHDD0']; // not required
$DSoS = $_POST['DSoS']; // not required
$NoHDD1 = $_POST['NoHDD1']; // not required
$DDoOS = $_POST['DDoOS']; // not required
$NoHDD2 = $_POST['NoHDD2']; // not required
$DSoOS = $_POST['DSoOS']; // not required
$NoHDD3 = $_POST['NoHDD3']; // not required

$DDoS .= "Data Destruction-At your site: ".clean_string($DDoS)."\n";
$NoHDD0 .= "#of HDD: ".clean_string($NoHDD0)."\n";
$DSoS .= "Data Sanitation-At your site: ".clean_string($DSoS)."\n";
$NoHDD1 .= "#of HDD: ".clean_string($NoHDD1)."\n";
$DDoOS .= "Data Destruction-At our site: ".clean_string($DDoOS)."\n";
$NoHDD2 .= "#of HDD: ".clean_string($NoHDD2)."\n";
$DSoOS .= "Data Sanitation-At our site: ".clean_string($DSoOS)."\n";
$NoHDD3 .= "#of HDD: ".clean_string($NoHDD3)."\n";
```

Comment: Where is your code for radio button. ??

Comment: Hi @rudi-coetzee. Please make sure your code is properly pasted before posting the question. If you can't edit it, can you provide a pastebin so we can fix it?

Comment: Thank you first time I am on here just really need help last bit to finish this project of mine.